# index file (.idx) can not be generated

Tags: indexing

I want to create an index in my document, so I use this code *(test.tex)*:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
    \section{Chapter 1}\index{index of test 1}
    \lipsum[6]\index{test}

    \printindex
\end{document}
```

When I compile the code, no test.idx is generated. I use Gummi editor, and these are it's preferences:

[image]

**So, what should I do in order to generate an .idx file?**

Comment: Compiling with `xelatex` (or `pdflatex`) on the command line generates the `.idx` file. The setup of `Gummi` (whatever that is...) seems to be wrong. And why are you using `\section{chapter 1}`?

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer I did compile it on the command line and it worked. After that I mentioned that Gummi does have a MakeIndex command to do the same job. *(quite embarrassing)*.